# Initiliazing int array with pointer type variable

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following code.

```
  FlowNProcess f1[3];
     int f1resources[2]={-1,0};   
     f1[1].resoures =f1resources; 



typedef struct FlowNProcess
{
    int id;
    int tt;
    int wt;
    Requirement *requirement;
    int *resoures;
    char *state;

} FlowNProcess;
```

Here since the resources is an int* so, I am first creating an array of size 2 and then
assigning the pointer to it. Is there a better way to achieve the same, maybe a one-liner

Comment: If you have that code in a function and `f1` is used outside that function, you have a bug.

Comment: If `f1[1].resoures` is a pointer, then it's not an array (making your title somewhat misleading). Perhaps you *should* make the `resoures` member an actual array, because then you can initialize it when you initialize `f1`.

Comment: @AKX That is true for any variable, how is that relevant?

Comment: You could use `f1[1].resources = (int[]){-1,0};`

Comment: added more info that could clear things

Comment: @Cheatah Thanks could we do something similar for the variables id, tt, wt rather than doing something like f1[1].id=1, f1[1].tt=0, f1[1].wt=0 ?

Comment: You can provide values when you initialize your array. `FlowNProcess f1[3] = {[0]={.id=0, .tt=1, .wt=123, ....}, [1]={ .id=1, .... }, [2]={ .id=2, ...}};`. Fields that are missing are set to 0.

Comment: You can also use compound literals to assign values after initialization: `f1[0] = (FlowNProcess){.id=0, tt = 42, resources=f1resources, ...};`

Comment: @Cheatah Just saying OP may have an issue if `f1resources` that's allocated on stack is used outside the stack frame.